# Why can you not do $u$-sub on the integral of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Every solution I've seen uses trig sub by letting $u=\tan (x)$.

Why can't I just let $u=x^2+1$?

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x$, then $dx=\dfrac{1}{2x}du$, so$$\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2x}\int \sqrt{u}\,du,$$so finally you get $\dfrac{(x^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}{12x}+C$.

Obviously this is wrong. But why? Can you just not substitute a function like $f(x)=x^2+1$ as $u$? I'm sure I'm making a mistake somewhere? Sorry in advance if this is obvious.

Comment: You cannot just take the $x$ outside the integral. $x = \sqrt{u-1}$ is not a constant

Comment: When you do a substitution, changing from $x$ to $u$, *everything* inside the integral has to be written in terms of the new variable; you can't have some stuff in terms of $u$ and some stuff in terms of $x$. So you cannot replace $\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$ with $\int\sqrt{u}\frac{1}{2x}\,du$, because this expression mixes $x$s and $u$s.

Comment: You CAN do a $u$-substitution, but it doesn't simplify the problem. You can always do a substitution, but usually only one or two will be fruitful, the others bringing you to a worst problem, if you follow the rules which you haven't done by "moving" the $1/{2x}$ out of the integral.

Comment: If you do that correctly, you have to rewrite $2x=2\sqrt{u-1}$ and then you have $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{u-1}} du$ which is not any easier than what you started with.

Comment: Ok, thank you all, this helps a lot!